# Table View not displaying SeekBar correctly Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having troubles getting my SeekBar to fill in my tableview.

This is it how it looks like:

[image: Table View]

My Code:

```
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvneg7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="e" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/totalE"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:max="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvneg8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"/>
            </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
                    android:layout_weight="1"
```

and it fixed it